# (redux / ngrx) Would you recommend to store UI related states?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

As far as i understand the principle of redux architecture, it's to ease the complexity when application state changes (business logic?).

But should one also handle presentation related states the redux way?
E.g. whether a sidebar is currently open, or a certain block of information is currently unfolded, etc.?

It's done that way in the [ngrx/store example page](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app). But since the application logic isn't depending in anyway of those presentation states, i can't really see the benefit of it.

Comment: Sooner or later you might get a feature request like this "If sidebar is opened hide something here" or "If search field is focused highlight something there" or "if I hide this block it should remain hidden after page reload". Having ui state in store helps to implement such request in very predictable manner.

Comment: One point in favor of storing UI state is that it means if you replay all the actions dispatched in a user's session, you'll end up with the UI *and* data in the exact same state as the first time. This means if you serialize the list of actions in your bug reports, you can play them back and reproduce the issue automatically. There's definitely trade-offs though - it means you have to keep track of a lot more info in your store.

Comment: thank's guys, that both sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

Every developer should decide that according to the requirements of their application. In the example app the state of the sidenav isn't truly relevant as u correctly pointed out, so is stored mainly for showcase purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do it for several reasons ( this is more specific to HTTP request loading status, error status etc.,)  :

- **No way to figure out http status, success or error** . When we dispatch, post or load request, it is just a one way flow . It wont give us if the request is success or if it gave an error. Imagine a post request gave validation error, we need to store this
- **Less code in component** , easy to write unit tests, easy to reuse code , easy to automate code . Services are always easy to test compared to components .
- **Update in multiple components** : Imagine we are showing summary on dashboard and actual data in the component . We need to show in dashboard that data is getting updated , not possible if status is stored in component
- **Store application state in localstorage**: One scenario I had to store the status of UI in the local storage. Users preference of side bar maximized or shortened , text size etc ., Even in these cases had to use store.

Answer (score 1):

I agree it will really depends on your requirements, but we can however consider some generic cases like manage notifications (in order to display one notification at a time), user connection (a lot of functionality might have a specific UI depending on that) etc.